# Node elimina los acentos al leer un archivo

Tags: nodejs, utf-8, acentos, tildes

Al leer un texto node me cambia palabras como Tecnología por Tecnolog�a

```
 const file = await readFile('./response.csv', 'utf-8');
 console.log(file);
```

Alguien puede ayudarme en el por qué ocurre esto? gracias

Comment: Buen día, ¿Haz intentado utilizar otro tipo de codificador aparte de `utf-8`? Intenta con `latin1`.

Comment: Quizás podrías hacer uso de alguna librería como iconv-lite o csvtojson.